# Which namespaces of xattrs a non root user can set in android?

Tags: android, ext4, selinux, file-attributes, non-admin

I know it isn’t possible to set`security.capabilities`attributes without uid 0 or CAP_SETFCAP.

However I was unable to find a complete list of what namespaces of names are allowed or what are those disallowed.

Answer (score 1):

This is documented in the [xattr(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/xattr.7.html) manual page:

> **Extended attribute namespaces**
>
> […] Currently,  the  `security`,  `system`,  `trusted`, and `user` extended attribute classes are
> defined as described below.  Additional classes may be added in the future.
>
> **Extended security attributes**
>
> […] Read
> and write access permissions to security attributes depend on the policy  implemented
> for  each  security  attribute  by  the  security module.  When no security module is
> loaded, all processes have read access to extended  security  attributes,  and  write
> access is limited to processes that have the CAP_SYS_ADMIN capability.
>
> **Extended system attributes**
>
> […] Read and write access permissions to system attributes  depend
> on the policy implemented for each system attribute implemented by filesystems in the
> kernel.
>
> **Trusted extended attributes**
>
> Trusted extended attributes are visible and accessible only to  processes  that  have
> the  CAP_SYS_ADMIN capability.  Attributes in this class are used to implement mecha‐
> nisms in user space (i.e., outside the kernel) which  keep  information  in  extended
> attributes to which ordinary processes should not have access.
>
> **Extended user attributes**
>
> […] The access permissions for user attributes are defined by the file permission
> bits: read permission is required to retrieve the attribute value, and writer permis‐
> sion is required to change it.

Comment: Ok, let’s narrow the answer. In reality I’m only interested on ᴘᴄ versions of android marsmallow.